# Choosing between two parsers with a common prefix

Tags: haskell, parsec

I am currently trying to write a simple parser in Parsec but keep running into problems regarding whitespace: As a minimal example, I have a parser that will parse two letters, either two lowercase or one uppercase and one lowercase. I would do this as

```
testP :: Parser String
testP = do
    lookAhead lower
    a1 <- lower
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
    <|> do
    a1 <- upper
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
```

This works as expected with strings like "as" or "Bs". Now I want to handle possible whitespace at the beginning of my input string. If I do

```
testP :: Parser String
testP = do
    spaces
    lookAhead lower
    a1 <- lower
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
    <|> do
    a1 <- upper
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
```

I would expect the program to be able to parse both "  as" and "  Bs" now, but for the second string I get an error "expecting space or lowercase letter" instead.
Okay, I thought the spaces would be parsed regardless of which option is taken, but apparently not so let's put another `spaces` at the start of the second option, like this:

```
testP :: Parser String
testP = do
    spaces
    lookAhead lower
    a1 <- lower
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
    <|> do
    spaces
    a1 <- upper
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
```

This still gives me the same error when I try to parse "  Bs", though. How am I misunderstanding whitespace handling here and how could I do this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<|>` will not try the second alternative if *anything at all* is consumed by the first parser. This is done to prevent space leaks. It was one of the foundational designs of parsec.

When `spaces` consumes some input, all is decided, that parser must now succeed - else, the alternative will not be tried and the whole machinery just fails. This is why you're observing this behavior. `spaces` consumes some input, `lookAhead lower` fails, the whole parser fails.

You *could* attain arbitrary lookahead with `try` and ensure the second alternative is tried even if the first consumes input, but you shouldn't, not in this case. Here, `spaces` is a *non-fatal* parser that is **preliminary** to both operations - so just use the parser *before* either of your alternatives.

```hs
testP :: Parser String
testP = spaces *> (do
    lookAhead lower
    a1 <- lower
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2]
    <|> do
    a1 <- upper
    a2 <- lower
    return [a1,a2])
```

Comment: Simpler still would be to push the `<|>` even deeper: `spaces *> liftA2 pair (try lower <|> upper) lower where pair x y = [x, y]`

Comment: (and assuming `lower` is the one from Parsec, you don't need the `try` or the `lookAhead`)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, this makes perfect sense now. Not sure how I did not realise myself that using spaces at the start meant it would of course consume something already.